# Is there a hook for nav menu item links to add custom css programatically?

Tags: menus, hooks

I know there is this **nav_menu_css_class** hook to add a custom class to the list items in the nav, but is there a similar hook to add a custom class to all link items in the nav? I want all my links in the nav to have this class:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#whatever">Sample page</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, and the hook is [`nav_menu_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/):

> `apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', array $atts, WP_Post $item, stdClass $args, int $depth )`
>
> Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item’s anchor element.

For example, this adds the `nav-link` class to the `<a>` tag only if the theme location (`$args->theme_location`) is exactly `my-location`:

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 3 );
function my_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'my-location' === $args->theme_location ) {
        // Get existing classes, if any.
        $class = $atts['class'] ?? '';

        // Now add your custom class(es).
        $atts['class'] = "$class nav-link";
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for the sample code.